# Similar posts shared in Facebook

Tags: facebook, sharing, facebook-like

My two friends, who are not friends with each other, shared the same cartoon. They appeared in sequence on my Home page.

Is there a way to combine them and combine the likes and comments in one shared posting?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is currently no way to do this.

Doing this would greatly complicate commenting on the cartoon - the system would not know which post the comment should be on.